# Import os doesn't not work in linux

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, suds

I just want to install the [suds library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds), but suddenly it wasn't proceeding because it was not finding the `os` library, so I tried to open my python and it results me an error. When I import the `os` library and there are some errors during the opening as well. Please, see the snapshot of my error when importing the library mentioned.

[image]

Is there any solution for this? Or do I need to reinstall python?

Comment: It's not just `os` that's not working. You Python install may be broken.

Comment: Most likely a problem with your python installation. How did you install it?

Comment: I did not yet do to reinstall it im just wondering if there other solution or something need to update the python.

Comment: @kindall might be right. have you tried importing anything else; such as `socket`?

Comment: I tried to import other librarys like sys, date etc., but I thin I have a problem when I importing the os

Comment: Are you sure you aren't working from a sandbox?

Comment: do you have a simple instruction of how to clean uninstall the python in Linux the install it again.

Comment: for `apt`: `apt-get purge python && apt-get install python`

Comment: and make sure you don't have a script named `os.py`; or a directory named `os`

Comment: i'll try to do that

Comment: @motoku its not working the apt command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125655/discussion-between-motoku-and-rock-n-roll).

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install a more recent version of Python - version 2.7.12 or later](https://www.python.org/downloads/). [All versions of Python 2.6 have been end-of-lifed and any use of Python 2.6 is actively discouraged](http://www.snarky.ca/stop-using-python-2-6).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and I already thinking of that, but in our situation our application is still only supports python 2.6.